# Firefox 4 show tools menu in button interface

Tags: firefox

I like the extra vertical space provided by the latest firefox beta (4b9). However, the button interface doesn't give you access to the tools menu.

I know that I can either temporarily enable the menubar by holding down the ALT key, but flipping a flag in about:config would be preferable. Does such a flag exist?

**Edit:** I want to be able to access the tools menu from the new button interface like you can with Bookmarks, History, Options, and Help.

[image: Tools menu not available]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Personal Menu](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/personal-menu/) addon for Firefox allows you to customize the Firefox menu button.

Using this extension you can add the tools menu and other handy menus that aren't in the button interface by default.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

did you try right-clicking somewhere and choosing what toolbars are allowed to be displayed?

In theory (I don't have Firefox 4), you should get a menu like this when right-clicking in certain areas:

[image]

Comment: No, the OP *doesn't* want to use that.

Comment: @muntoo: my answer was before his update. compare the times of posting.

Answer (score 0):

The [first](http://www.technixupdate.com/firefox-4-beta-get-old-style-file-menu-bar-in/) and [second](http://www.tothepc.com/archives/switch-to-classic-menu-bar-in-firefox-4/) search results for [Firefox 4 menu bar](http://www.google.com/search?q=firefox+4+menu+bar) give instructions on how to do this.

Or do you mean you want the compact titlebar with the menu permanently displayed?  If so, a user chrome CSS file is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to
"**Edit**: I want to be able to access the tools menu from the new button interface like you can with Bookmarks, History, Options, and Help."

Everything is available, just in a different place.

Web Search?  Just click in the search box or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

Downloads?  Right there on the right hand side of the Firefox button menu below Bookmarks and History.

Same with Add-ons, Set Up Sync, Private Browsing, and Options.

Clear Recent History is now under History, logically.

Only things that seem to be missing are Error Console (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> instead) and Page Info.

If you need them, why not submit Feedback to the Mozilla Firefox team asking them to add it?

Comment: I'm aware of how to get to the various controls--but getting access to the tools menu which many addons do is more annoying. I understand why they would want to hide the tools menu by default, but was hoping there would be a flag I could flip in about:config to show the tools menu in the button interface. I have also submitted feedback related to this feature. If it's not available yet, maybe it will be available in future builds.

Comment: Wrong Mikel, not everything is there. There are many addon or greasemonkey script options that default to the Tools menu, and you can't even get to them by going to addons and then selecting the addon and selecting options (Which is a big inconvenience as it is) but no, you have to go to the Tools menu

Comment: Indeed. There are a couple of addons that I use that make use of the tools menu. Perhaps there should be a special "Addons" menu for extensions to put their settings there?